# What do network icons mean in chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am seeing different icons beside posts to struts form in google chrome developer toold, network view. See below.

[image: Different icons for struts forms]

I have checked [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) but can't see any info?

Any ideas?  thanks.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the mime type returned?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there aren't a lot of options. Here is a screenshot of the resources from this page on stack overflow.

[image]

- If the mime type is `text/*` or even `application/javascript`, then you get the text icon.
- If the mime type is `image/*` then you get the actual image in the icon.
- An empty response will show the white icon.
- It looks like an empty image will show a square indicating the response had the mime type but no content (HTTP 204 as seen in the status column of my screenshot).

My guess is that the developer tools change often enough that they don't want to document the icons so they can change them later. The icon is simply a helpful "quick look" if you will. You should really look at the mime type, the status, and ultimately the content by clicking on the resource and getting into the details of the request/response.